# Fetch data from sqlite table and create json, removed signature

Tags: ios5

I need to create JSON from Sqlite database in a iphone application. I have 200 tables in my sqlite database. I need to send a combined json of all all record in these 200 tables to WCF service. Currently I am making json via append string as mentioned below but this is taking too much time.

```
        NSMutableString* jsonTypeStr = [NSMutableString string];
        [jsonTypeStr appendString:@"["];
```

I am new in iphone so don't know much about this. Is there any alternative method that is comparatively faster than append string formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://restkit.org/

Restkit makes this pretty easy, but make sure you read up on it. It takes a bit of work to integrate it into your project, but it will certainly be easier than doing it all by hand.

Additionally, there are other libraries, such as http://stig.github.com/json-framework/ that are excellent at converting between NSDictionaries and JSON objects, but these do not tie into core-data as well as restkit.